# Prove that for any three longest paths in a connected graph, there is a vertex which belongs to all three of them.

Tags: graph-theory

A couple of years ago during my extra curriculum Graph Theory class I received a problem from the teacher which he told me that it is unsolved till this day (3 years ago so I am not sure if this is still unsolved). But this problem often made me think about it and I would like to know to why my idea of proving it is most likely incorrect. The problem dates back from 1966 where Gallai asked whether every connected graph has a vertex that appears in all its longest paths. This have been proven for two longest paths in which I will link the proof of it here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2615/prove-that-every-two-longest-paths-have-at-least-one-vertex-in-common

The proof for two paths I understood completely and seems fairly simple. However, the problem that my teacher gave me was as follow:

**"Prove that for any three longest paths in a connected graph, there is a vertex which belongs to all three of them."**

So my attempt in proving this was as follow:

Take any graph $G$ that is connected. We have three longest paths, namely $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$.

There are 5 possible cases:

1. $P_1, P_2$, and $P_3$ share a common vertex (this is what we want to proof)
2. $P_i$ and $P_j$ share a common vertex but $P_i$ and $P_j$ do not share a common vertex with $P_k$.
3. $P_i$ and $P_j$ share a common vertex and Pk shares a common vertex with Pi but not with $P_j$.
4. $P_i$ and $P_j$ share a common vertex and $P_k$ shares a common vertex with $P_i$ and one with $P_j$ which is not the vertex that $P_i$ and $P_j$ already share commonly.
5. No longest paths share a common vertex

So if we disprove case 2 till 5, then it must mean that case 1 must be true:

Disproving case 2) Use the same reasoning for contradiction as in the problem of the two longest paths which I provided a link above. Contradiction that $P_i, P_j$, and or $P_k$ are the longest paths.

Disproving case 3) Since $P_i$ and $P_j$ share a common vertex, we know from the proof of the two longest path problem that this vertex should be in the middle of the path in order to preserve the property of these paths being the longest. Since $P_k$ shares a vertex with Pi and not with $P_j$, this means that it shares a vertex with $P_i$ that is not in the middle of its path, meaning there exists a path that is longer than the longest path $P_k$. Contradiction that $P_i$, $P_j$, and or $P_k$ are the longest path.

Disproving case 4) Same reasoning as in case 3. Contradiction that $P_i, P_j$, and or $P_k$ are the longest path.

Disproving case 5) Use the proof of the two longest path problem to show that there then would exist a longer path than the longest paths $P_i, P_j$, and or $P_k$. Contradiction that $P_i, P_j$, and or $P_k$ are the longest path.

This would mean that case 1 must be true and thus the three longest paths in a connected graph $G$ must share a common vertex.

I doubt that I have provided a correct proof with this so I am curious to why this would not be a correct proof. What am I missing in order to understand this problem better? I don't know how I do all these fancy mathematical writing on this website so I tried to write it as much in words as I could. Of course I would write this all more formally, but I am just curious about the direction of my idea behind it.

Thank you for your attention! :)

Comment: pretty good survey in this Master's thesis  http://mathematics.ceu.edu/sites/mathematics.ceu.hu/files/attachment/basicpage/29/kensellscott-final-2011.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I will definetly read it!

Comment: Why so many cases? If you've already proved that any two longest paths have a common vertex, then you know that cases 2, 3, and 5 can't arise, right? Or am I missing something?